# Geodata from Website JSON direct in GIS software

Tags: data, json

I would like to load some geodata into to QGIS or ArcGIS.

The geodata is on a Web page (restricted, so I can't can give you the link). In the Network dev tool is a GeoFeature with the JSON. I can copy the text, save as JSON and load, but is it possible to load pages directly and save the geodata in QGIS or ArcGIS?

Comment: What sort of JSON data?  Is it GeoFeature or GetFeature?

Comment: It starts like this {"featuresJson":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, imagining you use a GeoJSON or another remote compatible format in QGIS, you can provide directly in the url the couple user/password if you are using "Basic access authentication". The url will be similar to `https://user:password@your_url.yourdomain/your_subdirectory/your_geo_compatible_file.with_extension`. For the demo, a real URL can be use: [`https://demo:demo@labs.webgeodatavore.com/demo-auth/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson`](https://demo:demo@labs.webgeodatavore.com/demo-auth/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.geojson).

You can see a screenshot (url within works for the demo)

[image: Demo URL in QGIS with password]

You can also set the password using the UI like below (it does the same as the previous recipe, you just don't need to remember the "magic trick")

[image: Demo URL in QGIS with password set with UI]

If you are not using a common geospatial format file or you need more complex authentication, you need to provide more info for a better answer.

PS: According to your comment, it seems you are using GeoJSON, so the recipe should work fine

Comment: I have tried. I recieve: Download with "Protocol" source type has failed, do you wnat to try the "File" source type. The site is using a 2FA

Comment: Normal. The recipe I gave you is for "Basic access authentication". I'm not sure QGIS networking part currently manage 2FA.